# Why does the current Polish government favor distancing from EU despite a rather low Euroscepticism and possible serious financial consequences?

Tags: european-union, law, supreme-court, poland

According to [Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/2021/10/08/polexit-will-poland-s-nuclear-strike-on-eu-s-legal-order-lead-to-the-country-quitting-the-), Poland’s constitutional court on Thursday ruled the country's laws had supremacy of those of the European Union.

The article provides more context about the decision and a possible consequences:

> The European Commission has yet to unlock the payment of billions of
> euros to the country from the EU COVID recovery fund. It may very well
> refuse to sign up on the €57bn slated for Poland.
>
> "This is a huge chunk of money that they were expecting, and I cannot
> see this money being paid out now with this ruling," said Green MEP
> Daniel Freund.

While [the support for a possible "Polexit" is the highest ever](https://notesfrompoland.com/2021/08/03/support-in-poland-for-leaving-eu-highest-in-over-a-decade-finds-poll/), it is way below the required 50% to validate a referendum.

Did the Polish constitutional court give any rational of Poland's government to go so far into separating from EU, especially considering the huge amount of money at stake?

**Note:** I am especially curios about this as "political control of justice" is also an issue in Romania, but so far no government and constitutional court dared to explicitly distance so much from the EU (mostly due to financial reasons).

Comment: To me it seems that "Polexit" is not the main objective, but just a reply to the EU measures against the Polish Executive for its increased control over the judiciary. They would be ok with the EU if it were not that EU law may interfere with the current Executive plans. And the difference might then be summed up as "Romania's Executive prefers EU benefits even if it deters the Executive plans, Polish Executive prefers its own plan even if it cuts EU membership benefits." Or they believe EU's threats to be empty.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the Polish government wants to leave the EU. They're unhappy with many EU policies, but would doubtless want to have those policies changed and remain in the EU. I imagine the Polish government feels they can get the money and continue to do things their way, and the EU is a long way from actually kicking Poland out. So it's not about trying to leave the EU; it's about wanting to be treated differently by the EU.

Comment: Seems as debris from Brexit. The UK left the EU and (so far) it has not collapsed into anarchy and chaos, and it may be seen from the outside as (succesfully) pressing the EU into renegotiating and backpedalling on everything they agreed in the Brexit talks, such as the toll controls in Northern Ireland they are discussing right now. So it's probable that the Polish government thinks they can strong-arm the EU into having their cake and eating it.

Comment: @StuartF, to the best of my knowledge there isn't even a mechanism to expel a member state (and introducing one would require the Polish vote). The best the EU could to is to suspend membership rights, and Hungary would veto that. So I guess they can pretty much do what they want.